# pySpark - Add list to a dataframe as a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pySpark dataframe and a list of floating point numbers. The list has the same number of elements as the number of rows. I would like to add this list as a new column to an existing dataframe.

I tried using withColumn like this:

df.withColumn('newColumn', newList)

But it didn't work. Is there a straightforward way to do so?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.